# Sending mail with ASP.Net vNext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-core

In legacy ASP.Net and .Net in general, sending mail was accomplished via `System.Net.Mail` classes which resided in `System.dll`. Now with KRE, vNext doesn't seem to have `System.Net.Mail` as a separate package.

Referencing the `"net453"` framework in `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { },
    "aspnetcore50": { },
    "net453": {}       // <<< throws compilation errors
},
```

causes all hell to break loose with errors like:

> .NET Framework 4.5.3 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It virtually complains about all vNext dependencies that are part of kpm packages.

So, has anyone figured out a way to send mails using ASP.Net vNext yet?

**Note**

Even though `System` appears under References and even though Intellisense shows `System.Net.Mail` is available for use, the code doesn't compile. E.g., a simple statement like this, although appears valid,

```
using System.Net.Mail; 

var m = new MailMessage();
```

will throw compilation error such as:

> ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MailMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Update**

With latest Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5, they seemed to have fixed the intellisense glitch. Now `System.Net` doesn't have `Mail` namespace anymore. On a side note, the vNext project I created with VS 2015 preview is no longer working - I get an 403.3 error on the home page! Ah, the joy of working with beta software!

Comment: I think that with ctp 5 net 4.5.3 is not more, has been renamed 4.6

Comment: @LucaMorelli: That's another mess. The MSI says "Installing 4.5.3..." but in the Add/Remove Programs, it shows 4.6 and so does the references - e.g. `...\4.5.3\System.Core.dll`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `System.Net.Mail` your app can target only `aspnet50`. The `aspnetcore50` target has no such support (at least, not right now, as far as I know).

You shouldn't ever have your app target `net453` (which, as Luca mentioned in a comment, has since been renamed anyway) because ASP.NET 5 apps don't run on that platform.

An app that targets `aspnet50` can generally reference any .NET 4.0+ NuGet package or GAC reference.

So, in your case, remove the `net453` and `aspnetcore50` targets, and *within* the `aspnet50` target add a framework reference to `System.Net.Mail`.

A complete alternative would be to find some other existing NuGet package that has support for sending email in both `aspnet50` and `aspnetcore50`, but I doubt such a package exists at this time (though it no doubt will at some point in the future).

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot tonight. `net453` was a desparate attempt to get things working although I knew I shouldn't be targetting it. And the renaming is just cosmetic (see my comment above) I think (hopefully they will sort out this name mess before the final release).

Comment: That did the trick! I was adding more frameworks when it was time to delete some! :)

Comment: Kind of blows my mind that ASP.net 5 is in Release Candidate 1 Update 1 without a native way to send e-mail. That is a must have for most websites, isn't it? I understand with going cross-platform there is a lot of things to consider, but nearly every website I've ever worked on has required e-mail functionality (forgot password, contact us, receipts, etc). Is that the "gotcha" to keep people on the Windows/IIS stack? I see @Simon-Ordo posted about a potential 3rd party library, MailKit. Are there other good options?

Answer (score 3):

To follow up...  .NET team has stated that porting System.Net.Mail will be less than straightforward and will likely take a while.  That's a bummer since a production website usually does more than a little email sending.

In the meantime, someone just released a Core-Clr compatible email API called MailKit.  You can read about it here https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/212